# Update query in ado.net

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I wanted to update a column in my table, i have written the code it runs fine without any error also it displays the confirmation dialog box but the table is not updated whats wrong with the code.

```
    Dim sqlConn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    sqlConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\housingsociety.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"

    Try
        sqlConn.Open()
    Catch sqlError As Exception
        MsgBox(sqlError.Message, 0, "Connection Error!")
    End Try

    Dim sqlComm As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    sqlComm.Connection = sqlConn
    sqlComm.CommandText = "update committe_member set name = '@name' where name = 'member1'"


    Dim paramString As New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)
    paramString.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    sqlComm.Parameters.Add(paramString)
    paramString.Value = TextBox1.Text

    sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery()

    MsgBox("Record Sucessfully Altered", 0, "Confirmation!")

    sqlConn.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to quote the parameter in your SQL string.

Try the following:

```
sqlComm.CommandText = "update committe_member set name = @name where name = 'member1'"
```

I would also set the parameter value *before* adding it to the parameters collection:

```
paramString.Value = TextBox1.Text
sqlComm.Parameters.Add(paramString)
```

Comment: @nikhil - Have you profiled SQL server to see what is passed through to it?